# What Is the Correct Way to Close and Reopen a Form Declared as Public?

Tags: vb.net, com, add-in, excel-addins

My problem pertains to a COM add-in for Microsoft Excel. The use case is as follows: 1. User clicks the add-in's button on the ribbon. 2. A form window appears. 3. User interacts with the form window and clicks an OK button. 4. Various reports are generated, while a progress bar on the form window shows progress. 5. At the end of the process, the form window closes.

The process works as designed on the first run, but after the form window has been closed there is no way to start a new "session." From the user's perspective the add-in button becomes non-responsive. When run in debug mode from Visual Studio, clicking the add-in button a second time generates an error message: "Cannot access a disposed object."

Clearly something is wrong with the way I have hooked everything up, but I haven't been able to find a simple description of how to do it correctly. Here is what I have:

In a public class a number of public (or "global" variables) are declared; the form is also declared and instantiated here:

```
Public Class GlobalVariables

        Public Shared FormInstance As New MyFormDesign

End Class
```

The reason for declaring the form as a public object is to be able to be able to send progress values from various different subs and functions. The `GlobalVariables` class is imported by all modules that require it.

Behind the ribbon button is a single line of code:

```
FormInstance.Show()
```

Clicking the button instantiates and shows the form as intended. To keep things simple we can ignore the bulk of the code; simply clicking the "Cancel" button will trigger the problem. The code behind the "Cancel" button is straightforward:

```
Me.Close()
GC.Collect()
```

After closing the form it is no longer possible to create a new instance, per the error message cited above.

I don't really understand what is going on here, but it looks to me like the `GlobalVariables` class, once created, persists until the end of the Excel session. If that is correct the problem could presumably be cured by instantiating the form in a standard module. Instead of attempting to revive a form that has been disposed, the add-in would just create a new instance each time the user clicks the button. But if I go that route I can't figure out how to send progress values from other subs back to the form. It seems like a Catch-22.

There has got to be a way to both (a) create the form as a public object, and (b) create and destroy a new instance each time the add-in is run. Right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you have a `static` object there `Shared FormInstance`. When you close the Form, it gets disposed. There's nothing that recreates it. If you're trying to implement a sort of singleton pattern, some pieces are missing (as the piece that checks the instance for `null` and other similar checks). Can you use `ShowDialog()`? Do you need to persist the UI contents?

Comment: You are right, the form is a static object, not a variable. I have edited my question accordingly. As for recreating it, the intention was to create a new instance each time the button is clicked exactly the same way a new instance is created the first time. I assume that fails because the `GlobalVariables` declarations persist after the form has been closed. In answer to your last question, I don't need anything to persist; I would prefer to start from scratch each time the button is clicked.

Comment: Get rid of that `FormInstance` variable altogether. If you just use the default instance then it will work as you want. You access the default instance via the type name, so just use `MyFormDesign.Show()`. That will create a new instance if one does not already exist or the previous one has been disposed.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney: If I go that route, how do I make MyFormDesign public (or a "shared member")?

Comment: The simplistic fix, maybe too simple.  Why not instead of Me.Close() just me.Hide()?

Comment: @Hursey: With Me.Hide() the form will reappear with all the selections and input the user entered the last time around. I could couple this with a routine that resets all form controls, variables, and variable arrays, so that strictly speaking it could be made to "work" this way. But it seems like a terrible kludge. If you look at the use case at the top, I'm not trying to accomplish anything exciting or revolutionary. It should be possible to accomplish this in VB.NET using proper coding practices (I would think).

Comment: What about before the FormInstance.show() then, can you check if FormInstance = nothing, and if so create a new instance of it?

Comment: @Hursey: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried adding `If FormInstance Is Nothing Then Dim FormInstance As New MyFormDesign` before `FormInstance.Show()`, but it didn't work. On the second run I still get the "Cannot access a disposed object" error on `FormInstance.Show()` It must be because the initial `Public Shared` declaration persists even after the form has been disposed.

Comment: Even without the error, this would have led to other problems, as the declaration during the second run is non-public. I think the solution has to be to somehow unload all `Public Shared` declarations before exiting, if such a thing is possible.

Comment: Well I'm out of simple ideas then, Think you're going to have to restructure things suggested in other comments

Comment: Thank you for giving it your attention. I'll post on this page if I find a solution; otherwise I will go with the `Me.Hide()` kludge you suggested.

Comment: `As New` does not help you, it only works once.  The ribbon button code must be FormInstance = new MyFormDesign(), then FormInstance.Show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long journey, but I finally found out how to build the functionality described in my question. I will post the answer here, as it may help others in the future.

The challenge was to declare a form as `Public` in order to make it accessible throughout the project, so that subs and functions can send progress updates back to the form.

The problem was that the form, when declared and instantiated as described in my question, can only be created once per Excel session.

The solution is to declare the form as `Public` without instantiating it, then access it via a `Public ReadOnly Property`.

First, declare FormInstance as a public variable without instantiating it:

```
Public FormInstance As MyFormDesign
```

Second, define a `Public ReadOnly Property`. This establishes a way to call the form:

```
Public ReadOnly Property CallMyForm() As MyFormDesign    
    Get
        Return FormInstance
    End Get
End Property
```

Third, the ribbon button's `Click` event instantiates and shows the form:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    FormInstance = New MyFormDesign
    FormInstance.Show()

End Sub
```

Now a new form instance will be created each time the ribbon button is clicked, but the form can still be accessed via the CallMyForm  property.

Instead of ...

```
FormInstance.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
```

... we will use:

```
CallMyForm.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
```

This solves the conundrum laid out in the question.